Way to increase and decrease variables while keeping total for all variable constant (100%) in excel or R
Is there a way (in excel or R) to increase a certain variable while decreasing another (or multiple others) ultimately keeping the total constant for all variables.
Example:
Want to take this:

and turn to this

Or this (if I want to decrease 2 variables while increasing 1)

I would prefer in excel but can also use R if needed.

Yes.  Simply calculate the sum of your variables.  Divide each variable by the sum and then multiply by 100.  By the way, what you have illustrated is changing *observations (or rows) in a single variable (or column).

Increasing one, decreasing any
Indices to modify
inc <- 2
dec <- c(1, 3, 4)

Apply increase and find decrease
df$val[inc] <- df$val[inc] + 15
df$val[dec] <- df$val[dec] - ((sum(df$val) - 100) / length(dec))

df
  grp val
1  V1  15
2  V2  35
3  V3  15
4  V4  15
5  V5  20

sum(df$val)
[1] 100

Data
df <- structure(list(grp = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), val = c(20, 
20, 20, 20, 20)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df
  grp val
1  V1  20
2  V2  20
3  V3  20
4  V4  20
5  V5  20

